# Qt. Как сгенерировать HTML-файл с тегами?

Tags: html, qt

Я могу создать файл и через программный код записывать в него строки с тегами каждый раз, когда это понадобится. Но, если в Qt существует какая-нибудь библиотека, позволяющая более-менее автоматизировать этот процесс, то так определённо будет лучше.

Comment: Это удобнее делать с помощью JavaScript, а в Qt с JS можно работать через QJSEngine

Comment: Для QJSEngine нужно подключать библиотеку QML. К сожалению, задача требует не использовать её. Есть другие варианты?

Comment: https://wiki.qt.io/Handling_HTML#Manual_HTML_processing